# PHP code shows up as text. Does not execute actual code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have this page called order.php, which uses Ajax to call the serverTime.php in retrieving the server's date. Xampp is already turned on, and other php files from my other projects work fine.

But it returns the text of the code instead.

[image: PHP code not working.]

This is the code of order.php

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "serverTime.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>



<form name='myForm'>
Name: <input type='text' onChange="ajaxFunction();" name='username' /> <br />
Button: <input type='button' onClick="ajaxFunction();"/> <br/>
Time: <input type='text' name='time' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code of serverTime.php

```
<?php

echo date("H:i:s"); 

?>
```

Comment: There is no space between 'php' and 'echo' in your input field. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: Try using the raw URL. You find it is a configuration issue

Comment: Seems your server is not set up to execute PHP.

Comment: @Chris Actually, I have other projects that uses PHP and it works fine. Just not sure why this particular code doesn't.

Comment: @MarkCortejo Maybe the directory containing this project is configured differently? Try opening serverTime.php in your browser, does it give you the same output?

Comment: @Chris Hmm, I tried changing the url from file://.. to http://... It seemed to work, though. However, my other projects doesn't have any issues on the file://... url.

Comment: You need the server to run PHP. Your other PHP will not work with file:// URLs either